# OS X Script Editor - Open 3 images in 1 Photoshop file

Tags: image, macos, applescript, photoshop

Working in Script Editor, I have been trying to make an script that opens three selected JPEG files into a single Photoshop document.  I'm trying to arrange them one by one in a line. The code I wrote opens them, but in separate documents. This one is AppleScript, any other language that supports Script Editor would be appreciated too.

```
tell application "Finder"
set fileFolder to choose files with prompt "Please select your files"
set fileList to every file in fileFolder as alias list
repeat with I form 1 to number of items in fileList

set myFile to(item I of fileList)
tell application "adobe"
activate
open myFile

end tell
end repeat
end tell
```

If you have any suggestions including any other scripting language, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ImageMagick to join the files first before opening the combined file in Photoshop. If you want to do that, your code would become like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fileFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select your folder" default location (path to desktop folder as alias)
    set UnixPath to POSIX path of fileFolder
    do shell script "cd " & UnixPath & "; /usr/local/bin/convert *.jpg +append ~/Desktop/merged.jpg"
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2014"
        activate
        open alias "~/Desktop/merged.jpg"
    end tell
end tell
```

To do that, you would need to install ImageMagick, which is easiest to achieve using `homebrew`. Basically, you go to [here](http://brew.sh) and copy the line that installs it - I don't want to paste the line here in case it changes and outdates this answer, but copy that line and paste it into the Terminal.

Then type:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

and you will have access to ImageMagick for all your image processing needs - it is an EXTREMELY capable piece of software. You can try doing what the script above does in the Terminal by hand if you start the Terminal and type these commands

```
cd Desktop                                     # change directory to the Desktop
convert -size 200x100 xc:red red.png           # make a red image
convert -size 200x100 xc:blue blue.png         # make a blue image
convert red.png blue.png +append result.png    # join them side-by-side, saving as "result.png"
```

Here is the red image created above

[image]

here is the blue

[image]

and here is the combined result

[image]

Note that ImageMagick is just as happy with PNG, JPEG, TIFF or any other file formats and you can mix them freely.